# How can I display and organize my data right?

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of objects and I want three lines A, B and C for *every* object. I am trying this but is it still being messed on display:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyListSize * 3; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        Console.Writeline("C"); // any display function
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
        Console.Writeline("B"); // any display function
    else
        Console.Writeline("A"); // any display function

}
```

Could any point out what is my mistake?

Current Output:

> C A B C B A C A B C B A

Expected  Output:

> A B C A B C A B C A B C

Comment: Before you get downvoted into oblivion... pick *one* language.

Comment: What is with the language tag spam?

Comment: 0 % 3 is 0.  So either change the letters to match or start at 1.

Comment: Same logic, yes. same solution, no.

Comment: I agree with picking one language as said above.

Comment: And you've written the code in C#, but choose to keep only the C++ tag?

Comment: How about ? `for (int i = 0; i < MyListSize; i++) {
    Console.Writeline("A");
    Console.Writeline("B");
    Console.Writeline("C"); }`
} or ` `for (int i = 0; i < MyListSize; i++) 
    Console.Writeline("A B C ");
` ?

Comment: Get pen&paper and process the code by hand. Your question is not about any programming language apparently, but an algorithm. Let that apart, the name `WriteLn` implies it prints every output on a single line, not seperated by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyListSize * 3; ++i) {
    switch (i % 3) {
        case 0:
            Console.Writeline("A"); // any display function
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.Writeline("B"); // any display function
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.Writeline("C"); // any display function
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Displayed "B A C B A C B A C B A C" and what if I can't use `switch()` and it is in another language than c++?

Comment: @Nope: The code is correct. If you did not get the result, you did something wrong. If you cannot use `switch`, use whatever the language provides. Any language provides a conditional statement/function at least. This is no tutorial site, you are expected to do some abstraction effort on your own.

Comment: It works, and the output is A B C A B C A ... you can change the switch statement with ifs

Answer (score 0):

This should work for c# and c++:

```
for (int i = 0; i < YourListSize * 3; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        cout << "A"; // or Console.Writeline()
    if (i % 3 == 1)
        cout << "B";
    if (i % 3 == 2)
        cout << "C";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**. As @juharr said, your `for` loop starts with 0 and `0(mod 3) = 0`, so your sequence starts with `C`. Just replace `for` line with:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= MyListSize; i++)
```

.. or refine you `ifs`

---

Until you tell us clearly what you want there'll be magic predictions, but not the solutions. Like this:

```
var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, "A", "B", "C");
for (int i = 0; i < MyListSize; i++) 
{
    Console.Writeline(s);
}
```